# Set up libraries with pip on mac os

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, pip

I need to instal 2 packages in python

```
pip install requests
pip install websocket-client
```

There is a video on youtube, which perfectly shows how to do it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=237dNNQhD3Q I tried it on windows and it works perfectly. However I need to install these packages on mac.
Firstly, I followed the steps described here to download pip https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pip-in-macos/

The output in terminal is following:

```
MacBook-Pro-3:~ GSuh$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py > get-pip.py
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
100 1842k 100 1842k 0 0 7005k 0 —:--:— —:--:— —:--:— 7005k
MacBook-Pro-3:~ GSuh$ sudo python get-pip.py
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-pro.. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/GSuh/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pip
Downloading pip-20.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
|################################| 1.5 MB 2.6 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-20.2.4
MacBook-Pro-3:~ GSuh$ sudo pip install requests
WARNING: The directory '/Users/GSuh/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting requests
Downloading requests-2.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
|████████████████████████████████| 61 kB 375 kB/s
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
Downloading certifi-2020.6.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
|████████████████████████████████| 156 kB 607 kB/s
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2
Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
|████████████████████████████████| 133 kB 3.6 MB/s
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
Downloading urllib3-1.25.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
|████████████████████████████████| 127 kB 10.4 MB/s
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
Downloading idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
|████████████████████████████████| 58 kB 649 kB/s
Installing collected packages: certifi, chardet, urllib3, idna, requests
Successfully installed certifi-2020.6.20 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.10 requests-2.24.0 urllib3-1.25.11
MacBook-Pro-3:~ GSuh$ sudo pip install websocket-client
WARNING: The directory '/Users/GSuh/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting websocket-client
Downloading websocket_client-0.57.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (200 kB)
|████████████████████████████████| 200 kB 2.4 MB/s
Collecting six
Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Installing collected packages: six, websocket-client
Successfully installed six-1.15.0 websocket-client-0.57.0
MacBook-Pro-3:~ GSuh$ python

WARNING: Python 2.7 is not recommended.
This version is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.
Future versions of macOS will not include Python 2.7.
Instead, it is recommended that you transition to using 'python3' from within Terminal.

Python 2.7.16 (default, Aug 24 2019, 18:37:03)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.32.4) (-macos10.15-objc-s on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
»> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
»>
```

As a result, packages deemed to be downloaded however I cannot use them. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing python packages on a Mac is a bit of nightmare. Fortunately virtual environments can save the day to make this all a lot more manageable. There are a lot of guides out there that will help you set this up, but it comes down to your PYTHONPATH being set properly and pointing to the proper libraries.

If you're not careful you'll end up with the [dreaded xkcd python environment](https://xkcd.com/1987/). This is a common problem and has been addressed many times through different projects such as `pipenv` and `pyenv` and `venv` and probably others.

I strongly encourage you to set up a virtual python env with the following tools:

- Homebrew
- PyEnv
- Pipenv or virtualenv (optional)

[Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) allows you to quickly install the tools you need and various other dependencies along with the appropriate configurations in a somewhat consistent manner.

Once you have homebrew installed you can easily install [`pyenv`](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac#what-to-do) which allows you to create multiple python environments that are internally consistent.

From there you can install `pip` within your new PyEnv virtual environment and get a base environment set up.

I prefer to use a [Pipenvironment](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenvironments-ref) within the PyEnviron for each project to prevent conflicting dependencies.